# Does racism against aliens exist in the Star Trek world, given that aliens are so different from humans?

Tags: star-trek, aliens

Sad to say, it is human nature to be uncomfortable with other races or even dislike them, particularly if they are very different from us. The contrast between humans and aliens are even greater. Therefore, the likelihood of racism against aliens is even higher.

It is hard to believe advancement of technology can change human nature. It is quite unimaginable that humans can shed their basic selfish and greedy nature and expect most of them to become kind saints.

What are some incidents of alien racism, if any, in Star Trek?

Comment: Can't write a full answer right now, but racism and anxiety is a huge plot point in many later episodes, especially Enterprise, but also in a few first contact incidents of Voyager.

Comment: In TOS there's a fair amount of prejudice against the Klingons, the TNG episode "The Drumhead" deals with fear of the Romulans, and a Starfleet officer mentions how certain species aren't meant for certain roles when explaining why he doesn't want to serve under Data...there is definitely still prejudice/racism in Starfleet, especially when it comes to species not obviously "sentient"...unfortunately I can't type up a well sourced answer but it's a start haha

Comment: @VapedCrusader in the Drumhead episode I think it was, it even goes further with trying to consider the guy guilty solely for the reason of having "romulan blood." Which I would consider racist (judging someone because of their "blood") but I keep being assured is just a normal thing in much of the rest of the world.

Comment: The duplicates address racism (by humans) toward various alien races including the Klingons, Ferengi and Vulcanians.

Comment: Also McCoy’s kind of a dick to Spock, right? Calls him green-blooded all the time.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Spock's hardly the model of inter-species tolerance either. I always ascribed their jibes to good-natured banter rather than actual race prejudice. They clearly respect each other.

Comment: The episode **Star Trek: TNG" *The High Ground (1990)*** is a clear allusion of the Jewish Israeli-Arab Israeli situation,which itself is based upon racism:Jewish Israelis have,by Jewish Israeli law,more rights than Arab Israelis, they can own certain pieces of land while the Arab Israelis can't. It's an episode for which racism is the **basis**, even if the episode is more about the hypocrisy of Star Fleet, which, ultimately supports a racist government by inaction. Goes against 2nd Robotic law, which Asimov has argued are HUMAN laws after all http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708799/reviews-2

Comment: I have to wonder if perhaps aliens wouldn't be *so* different that they just wouldn't trigger our "other tribe" reaction.  They might inspire screaming panic, however...  ;D

Comment: Definitely prejudice against the Klingons in Kirk's time, as shown by Kirk himself in The Undiscovered Country. Some of the Vulcans display patronizing racism towards humans. It seems to be more other hostile species that are prejudiced, though, like the Cardassians and the Bajorans and the Romulans and the Remans. BTW the conflict in The High Ground is based on Northern Ireland, the episode was even banned in the UK when it was first aired because of Data's comments regarding the "Irish Unification" of 2024.